# show and hide DIVS at a given time

Tags: html, timer, hide, show

I'm in big trouble, I'm creating a multiple choice questionnaire, where each issue is a DIV, I need a javascript that apart from the DIVS roll at a given time, the screen shows the seconds this time, the problem is that every question must have a time
different, eg the No. 1 already has 10 seconds to question No. 2 is 15 seconds, for example, can anyone help me?

Comment: So, what have you tried? Can we see some code?

Comment: please post an example of your code. rent-a-coder this isn't

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `setTimeout` Jquery's function, playing with `getElementById('yourid').style.display = "none";`

Here's an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YQgH7/) I made for you.